# Enabling GWT CheckBox after disabling it leaves text grayed out in Chrome browser

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, gwt, checkbox

I am using GWT on Google App Engine. I have some logic in my view to enable and disable certain `CheckBox` widgets based on other input on the page.

There is an initial state of the checkboxes that is set immediately after creating the checkboxes in the view panel (after an RPC to obtain data in onLoad()). This initial state displays the checkboxes correctly, with a few of them enabled and a few of them disabled. The enabled checkboxes are dark gray with black text. The disabled checkboxes are light gray with gray text.

This is the method that creates the checkboxes from the RPC data:

```
public void onSuccess(MyData[] result) {
    for (MyData t : result) {
        ...
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(t.getName());
        String name = "chk" + t.getId();
        cb.setName(name);
        checkBoxPanel.add(cb);
    }
    updateCheckBoxes();
    ...
}
```

This is the method that updates the checkboxes enabled state:

```
void updateCheckBoxes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxPanel.getWidgetCount(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)checkBoxPanel.getWidget(i);
        if (someLogic(cb.getName())) {
            cb.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
            cb.setEnabled(false);
            cb.setValue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

When this same method that enables and disables the checkboxes is called to update their state after user input triggers a change, the checkboxes themselves are updated correctly (change from dark gray to light gray and vice versa), but the checkbox text is not updated. The text remains in the first state it was changed to after adding the checkboxes initially. The initially enabled checkboxes have black text, the initially disabled checkboxes have gray text.

The checkboxes behave correctly after they're updated. It's only the text that is incorrect. The checkboxes themselves changing from dark gray to light gray is not an adequate indication of their state as it's much harder to see compared to the text color next to them (besides the text color being misleading).

I didn't notice this being an issue after I first deployed this code. I only just noticed it now. So I'm not sure if something changed in Google App Engine possibly, or if I only just noticed it. Is this a bug in GWT? Any suggestions on a workaround? Or is there something I'm not doing correctly to have the text color update with the checkbox enabled state.

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems to be specific to the Chrome browser. The checkboxes behave as they should in Firefox. This may be an issue introduced in a recent Chrome update, possibly why I don't remember seeing it when I first deployed this code. Seems like Google's GWT on App Engine should work best in their own Chrome browser. I am using Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m.

Comment: How do you create these checkboxes? Do you set any styles on them (if you do, how)?

Comment: I added the method that creates the checkboxes. It's pretty basic. I don't add any styles anywhere.

Comment: What version of GWT do you use? Do you see the same behavior in all browsers?

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.6.0. I just noticed there's a 2.6.1 update I will try now. I do not see this behavior in Firefox now that I tested it there. I am seeing it in Chrome. So maybe it's an issue introduced by an update to Chrome since I don't remember seeing it before.